# Group Policy Object mapping network drive denied because it's empty?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012, group-policy, windows-8

I have a GPO to map a network drive, but it's being denied, and a GP Result report lists it as denied because the GPO is empty:
[image]

The Group Policy Settings:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your screenshot, you are creating a network share (to **create** a file share and not to connect to it!)

You should use the following GPP: **User** Configuration -> Preferences -> **Drive Maps**

Comment: Yep, I discovered this this morning.